# list values to multiple rows in xpath

Tags: xml, oracle

Am getting single rows return multiple values error. how to print the multiple results in separate rows.

```
select 
  (select  G_k_2_3_r_1
  from
   gom_e2br3_imp_queue imp,
        XMLTABLE ( xmlnamespaces('urn:hl7-org:v3' as "xa"), '/xa:ingredientSubstance[@classCode="MMAT"][@determinerCode="KIND"]' passing b1.G_k_2_3_r_1_XML
        columns
         G_k_2_3_r_1 Varchar2(4000) path 'xa:name')
         )
        "G_k_2_3_r_1"

FROM
GOM_e2br3_imp_queue imp,
        XMLTABLE (  xmlnamespaces('urn:hl7-org:v3' as "xa"),  '/xa:MCCI_IN200100UV01' PASSING imp.xml_data 
        COLUMNS 
G_k_2_3_r_1_XML  XMLTYPE PATH 'xa:PORR_IN049016UV/xa:ingredientSubstance[@classCode="MMAT"][@determinerCode="KIND"]'

)
B1;
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                      
<MCCI_IN200100UV01 ITSVersion="XML_1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 MCCI_IN200100UV01.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">                                                                                     
    <id extension="N.1.2" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.3.22"/>                                                                                 
    <creationTime value="20101214151617"/>                                                                                  
    <responseModeCode code="D"/>                                                                                    
    <interactionId extension="MCCI_IN200100UV01" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.6"/>                                                                                 
    <name code="N.1.1" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.989.2.1.1.1" codeSystemVersion="1.01"/>
<PORR_IN049016UV>
<ingredientSubstance xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND">
    <code code="G.k.2.3.r.2b" codeSystem="TBD-Substance" codeSystemVersion="G.k.2.3.r.2a"/>
    <name>G.k.2.3.r.1</name>
</ingredientSubstance><ingredientSubstance xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND">
    <code code="G.k.2.3.r.2b" codeSystem="TBD-Substance" codeSystemVersion="G.k.2.3.r.2a"/>
    <name>G.k.2.3.r.1</name></ingredientSubstance>
<ingredientSubstance xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND">
    <code code="G.k.2.3.r.2b" codeSystem="TBD-Substance" codeSystemVersion="G.k.2.3.r.2a"/>
    <name>G.k.2.3.r.1</name>
</ingredientSubstance><ingredientSubstance xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND">
    <code code="G.k.2.3.r.2b" codeSystem="TBD-Substance" codeSystemVersion="G.k.2.3.r.2a"/>
    <name>G.k.2.3.r.1</name></ingredientSubstance>
</PORR_IN049016UV>
/MCCI_IN200100UV01>
```

Comment: Huh?  Please edit the question to show the error, and sample XML data used for the query.  thanks

Comment: Hi upon executing above sql statement am getting below error:                 
   ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Wherein i need to pull all <name> tag values one below another in multiple rows